# make an icon image more pronounced

Tags: images, adobe-photoshop

I need to make an icon image more pronounced

[image: arrow image]

I need to make it such that the curved grey border is solid and not pixelated as in here now. A little help with quick photoshop tips will be helpful. Thanks

Comment: give example with Jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1):

The best way to make an image like this more pronounced would be to make sure you created a large version first (all the graphic work I do, I do at a min of 600x600 90+ DPI). If you already have it created large next is it done through vector imaging or just painting? For a more crisp image it is best to use vectoring or the shape tools (this also allows for easy modification later and for the image to be sized to anything). You create large, then save it small, if slightly pixleated save in higher format (I prefer png-24) or you need to go back and stretch